# How to reinitialize lazy loaded entity?

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, vaadin

I have an entity Person:

```
class Person {
  String name;
  String phone;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
}
```

When I display persons at table I don't want to load addresses.
When I open edit dialog, I want to display addresses too. But I got Lazzy loading exception (there is no active session).

How can I reinitialize Person instance to load addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call another method which will reload the person from database along with his addresses:

```
public Person loadPersonWithAddresses(Long personId) {
    Person p = (Person) getSession().get(Person.class, personId);
    Hibernate.initialize(p.getAddresses());
    return p;
}
```

or

```
public Person loadPersonWithAddresses(Long personId) {
    String hql = "select distinct p from Person p"
                 + " left join fetch p.addresses"
                 + " where p.d = :id";
    return (Person) getSession().createQuery(hql)
                                .setLong("id", personId)
                                .uniqueResult();
}
```

to do it in a single query.